# Binding a Vertex Buffer to a Compute Shader to modify the data?

Tags: c++, directx, shader, directx-11

I am trying to modify the contents of a Vertex Buffer using a Compute Shader.

The problem is I don't know how to make the Vertex Buffer available to the Compute Shader, how I should bind it.

Is it possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a unordered access view for the vertex buffer `ID3D11UnorderedAccessView`

Assign it to the CS by:

```
ID3D11UnorderedAccessView *uavs[] = {pUnorderedAccessView};
UINT offsets[2] = {0};
m_pd3dImmediateContext->CSSetUnorderedAccessViews( 0, 1, uavs, offsets);
```

Comment: Thank you! I wasn't sure which one to use.